# Android - rotate layout and keep touch functionality of the views

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an activity that must keep landscape orientation at all times so it is set like that in the manifest. However I want it to respond to the device's physical orientation changes by rotating the views inside it.
I am detecting the orientation changes using the accelerometer and rotate the views as necessary.

When I rotate the following layout, it appears rotated but the views are not clickable at their new positions. However if I click at their old position then a click is indeed performed.

How do I implement this so that the views are INDEED rotated and not just look rotated?

```
SeekBar text
-----------▢------

SeekBar text
-----▢------------

▢ Checkbox
▢ Checkbox
▢ Checkbox

 _______________
 |    button    |
 ----------------
```

This is my code

```
view.clearAnimation();
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(startDegrees, endDegrees,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f);
anim.setDuration(400);
anim.setFillBefore(true);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: thats funny, instead of animating, you can directly set the orientation of the device. look for the codes that are recommended for changing the orientation withoit causing illegal state exception.

Comment: The question is what can I do to meet the mentioned specifications...not if they are likeable.

Comment: In that case, can you upload the code where you are assigning and listening for touches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you cant use a RotateAnimation because it only moves the pixel on the screen, so an OnClickListener does not animate with it. Use [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html)(or [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)) instead and your OnClickListener should work on the new position :

Heres an example using ViewPropertyAnimator :

```
view.animate().rotation(endDegrees).setDuration(400);  // or .rotationBy(endDegrees)
```